# Записать данные в словарь из excel

Tags: python-3.x, excel

Есть таблица excel:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь записать данные в словарь:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('Таблица исключений.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['Лист1']
for row in sheet_ranges.iter_rows(row_offset=0):
    a = row[0].value
    c = row[1].value
    b = {}
    b[a] = c
    print(b)
```

Получаю:

```
Р ЛЬВОВИЧ': 10003359}
{'МОКРОУСОВА ОЛЬГА АНАТОЛЬЕВНА': 10003360}
{'НАГЛЕНКО ВАЛЕРИЙ ВЛАДИМИРОВИЧ': 10003361}
```

Не понимаю, почему данные отображаются не все? И когда пытаюсь получить значение:

```
print(b['МОКРОУСОВА ОЛЬГА АНАТОЛЬЕВНА'])
```

Выходит ошибка:

```
KeyError: 'МОКРОУСОВА ОЛЬГА АНАТОЛЬЕВНА'
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне исправить ситуацию? Заранее благодарна за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что словарь каждый раз пересоздается:

```
for row in sheet_ranges.iter_rows(row_offset=0):
    b = {}  # пусто!!!
    b[a] = c  # всегда хранит только (последнее) одно значение
```

Почему бы не вынести его за цикл?!

```
b = {}  # до цикла
for row in sheet_ranges.iter_rows(row_offset=0):
    b[a] = c
print(b)  # после цикла
```

Comment: спасибо большое. Все сработало!!!